# Can you get a list of available updates for app (in-app updates)

Tags: android, android-update-app

With [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) we are able to check whether there's an update available for our app. We are also able to set a priority (an integer between 0-5) for the update when creating the release.

Now let's assume the user doesn't use the app for a while. He/she might miss a couple of updates. One of these missed updates might be of high priority followed by an update of lower priority. When the user opens the app after a while, our app checks for an available update and sure enough there's one available. But if I understand correctly the check only shows the most recent update and that update has a low priority.

My question is can you get a list of all uninstalled/available updates for your app or is there any other way to check whether the user has missed high priority updates? This way we could prompt an immediate update even if the latest update is not of high priority.

Comment: Doesn't the latest update codebase also include all the previous updates? So if the user updates tot the latest version he/she will get all the previous updates as well?

Comment: Yes the codebase includes the previous changes unless the developers knowingly reverted the changes.